# Second drive inaccessible from OS but accessible in Recovery mode (which shows no issue)

Tags: hard-drive, macos, imac, disk-utility

I have a iMac 2008 with 2 drives.
Main drive is an SSD in the DVD bay and second drive 3,5" HHD in the original iMac disk bay.
After a reboot before which everything was working just fine second drive is inaccessible from OS but if I boot in recovery mode I can see also the second drive and also all the files in it.
I run SMART and no issue appears in the disk.

I'm attaching some pictures (text is in Italian but the meaning should be very clear).

[image: diskutil list from OSX]

[image: SOS disk aid from Recovery Mode]

[image: diskutil list from Recovery Mode]